# Determining values of Polynomial expansion for Generating Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

Polynomial Expansion:

$ (1 - x^m)^n  = 1 - \binom{n}{1}x^m   \; + \binom{n}{2}x^{2m} \; +...+\; (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{km}$

Given that f(x) = $ (1 - x^{11}) \; let  \; a_i \; denote \; the \; i^{th} \; coefficient  \; for \; f(x)$

My textbook then goes on to say that the only non-zero coefficient for f(x) is
$ a_0=1 \; and \; a_{11}=-1$

can someone please explain to me why every other value in between is zero for f(x) because I do not see it.

This was the original question

[image]

Would it be because when simplifying f(x) and g(x) the only values remaining for f(x) is the coefficients that denote when f(x) is essentially 0?

Comment: "The only nonzero coefficients in $f(x)=1-x^{11}$ are $a_0=1$ and $a_{11}=-1$." Do you see any other nonzero coefficients in $1-x^{11}$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the relation

$ (1 - x^m)^n  = 1 - \binom{n}{1}x^m   \; + \binom{n}{2}x^{2m} \; +...+\; (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{km}$

can not be written with arbitrary coefficients. Moreover you should use the index $k$ along with the coefficient $a$. The last point is that the author is talking about this equation (expansion)

$f(x) = a_0 1 - a_1 \binom{n}{1}x^m   \; + a_2 \binom{n}{2}x^{2m} \; +...+\; a_k (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{km}.$

Given that $~f(x) = 1 - x^{11}~$ it should be clear why $~a_0 = 1$, $~a_{11}=-1~$ and all other coefficients zero.

Regards

Comment: ahh yes.. thank you i basically confused coefficient with index. thank you so much again